# Waiting for futures to complete

Tags: flutter

I am struggling with futures and nested futures. I need to wait for the loadRecordData before it is returned as it is not loaded when trying to display it in a FutureBuilder/List

This reads records from the database and returns them in a list

```
Future<List<Record>> readRecords(Query query) async {
  final dbHelper = DatabaseHelper();
  final db = await dbHelper.database;

  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.rawQuery(query.sql,query.params);

  return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
    return fillRecord(maps[i]);
  });
}
```

This fills the Record Class with the fields from the query, and then depending on what type of record is loaded, load more data using more database queries.

I think the issue I have is I am not waiting for loadRecordData to complete. I have tried making this function async, but then it needs to return a future, which bubbles up and requires the list above to also be a list of futures.

```
Record fillRecord(map)  {
  Record rec = Record(
      id: map['id'],
      recordType: map['recordType'],
      title: map['title'],
      url: map['url'].toString(),
      imageUrl: map['imageUrl'],
  );

  // await rec.loadRecordData();
  // return rec;

    // I think this is the problem area. I need to wait for this function to complete, but cannot make it work.
    rec.loadRecordData(); 

    return p;
}
```

This is part of the Record class to update record with extra data

```
Future<void> loadRecordData() async {
    readRecordMetas(id).then((ListRecordMeta> myMeta) async {
      metaData = myMeta;
      if (postType == 'event') {
        String? orgId = getMetaValue("organisation");
        if (orgId != null) {
          readRecord(orgId).then((Record? org) async {
            eventOrganisation = org;
          });
        }
      }
    });
```

How can I be sure that loadRecordData completes before returning list;

Comment: use the keyword await before the readRecordMetas

Comment: Thanks, but still doesn't do it. If I add the await, and print out before rec.loadRecordData, during and after, I get the before and after many times before I start getting the during

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not awaiting all async calls that you are making. I would rewrite `loadRecordData` to

```
Future<void> loadRecordData() async {
  metaData =  await readRecordMetas(id);
  if (postType == 'event') {
    String? orgId = getMetaValue("organisation");
    if (orgId != null) {
      eventOrganisation = await readRecord(orgId);
    }
  }
}
```

And then `fillRecord` as

```
Future<Record> fillRecord(map) async {
  Record rec = Record(
      id: map['id'],
      recordType: map['recordType'],
      title: map['title'],
      url: map['url'].toString(),
      imageUrl: map['imageUrl'],
  );

  await rec.loadRecordData();
  return rec;

}
```

and finally inside `readRecords` change

```
  return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
    return fillRecord(maps[i]);
  });
```

to

```
  return await Future.wait(maps.values.map((i) => fillRecord(i)));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Future<void> loadRecordData() async {
  final recordMetas = await readRecordMetas(id);
  if (postType == 'event') {
    String? orgId = getMetaValue("organisation");
    if (orgId == null) return; 
    eventOrganisation = await readRecord(orgId);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).